# is quicksort faster in javascript with or without pop and shift

Tags: javascript, optimization

I'm following some videos on algorithms in javascript and found that the instructor implemented a quicksort using something like the following code:

```
function quickSort(arr){
  if(arr.length <= 1) return arr
  const pivot = arr[arr.length - 1]
  let left = []
  let right = []
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++){
    if (arr[i] < pivot) {
      left.push(arr[i])
    } else {
      right.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
  return [].concat(quickSort(left),pivot,quickSort(right))
}
```

When I wrote my own version, instead of using a for loop and having to worry about ignoring the pivot or having a lengthy for loop, I used pop and shift like so:

```
function quickSort(arr){
  if(arr.length <= 1) return arr
  const pivot = arr.pop()
  let left = []
  let right = []
  while(arr[0]){
    if (arr[0] < pivot) {
      left.push(arr.shift())
    } else {
      right.push(arr.shift())
    }
  }
  return [].concat(quickSort(left),pivot,quickSort(right))
}
```

The comments for the video (youtube) said that my version was terrible but gave no further explanation. I'm not sure what I should be searching for in google. And from what I can tell it's just as quick in both cases. Can someone tell me the issue with using pop or shift?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? https://www.measurethat.net/

Comment: Your code is `O(N^2 * logN)` (because `Array.prototype.shift` is linear), and their code is `O(N * logN)`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks, bookmarked.

Comment: You should also check whether your version produces the correct result, of course.

Comment: @zerkms is the shift itself time consuming?

Comment: @suavocado it is `O(N)`

Comment: I don't see what you mean by "*worry about ignoring the pivot or having a lengthy for loop*".

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan they both work as expected in all my test cases, I'm really just curious about the speed.

Comment: Your algorithm empties the input array. Alone that mutation is a horrible thing.

Comment: @Bergi I simply meant that when i choose a pivot from the array you have to ensure that the pivot doesn't end up being repeated. It seems easier to remove it from the array altogether. And the while loop is just easier to read. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @suavocado you should not care about the "speed" until you learn basics of algorithms and Big-O analysis (otherwise what you do - is a "black magic")

Comment: @suavocado Well yeah, I disagree with both of your points. Also `while(arr[0])` is plain wrong, it doesn't work when your array contains zeroes or other falsy values. You need to do `while(arr.length > 0)` at least.

Comment: @zerkms Sure that current shift implementations are linear and not faster due to e.g. preallocation by the JS engine?

Comment: @le_m not sure how you can "preallocate" a shift operation. https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/js/array.js#L534

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone tell me the issue with using pop or shift?

I presume that the issue is that *modifying* the input array with `pop` and / or `shift` is more expensive than simply reading elements from it.  Each `shift` in particular could and probably does cost O(N), though in principle that depends on the implementation.

Note that `push`ing into new per-partition arrays could also incur some unneeded cost.  At minimum, it incurs more memory overhead than a traditional quicksort implementation, which would sort the input array in place.

Comment: @le_m that's how it is defined in the standard and in the V8. Also see the "could" word + "though in principle that depends on the implementation".

Comment: @le_m https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.shift --- that's how the standard defines it. And it's linear. Not sure I see your point here.

Comment: @le_m I did not say anything about runtime performance (it was you actually), sorry. I said "that's how it is defined in the standard and in the V8". Both are linear. What is your point here?